# How can I start a process in PowerShell with arguments in quotes?

Tags: powershell

In my command line, I start my process like this:

`ffmpeg -f dshow i video="Integrated Camera" c:\test.mp4`

I want to do the same in PowerShell.

I tried:

```
$args = " -f dshow i video='Integrated Camera' c:\test.mp4"
Start-Process -FilePath ffmpeg.exe -ArgumentList $args
```

And I tried:

```
$args = " -f dshow i video=\"Integrated Camera\" c:\test.mp4"
Start-Process -FilePath ffmpeg.exe -ArgumentList $args
```

But in both cases, FFmpeg won't start.

How can I put `"` in my arguments?

Comment: Escape the inner quotes with a backtick not backslashes. Backslashes error when I try that manually here.

Comment: -ArgumentList expects the parameters to be comma separated, try adding commas instead of spaces to $args.

Comment: like this? $args = " -f dshow, i video=integrated Camera, c:\test.mp4" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first urge caution that [Start-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) may not be exactly what you desire. This will open a new process in a new command window (cmd).

I would encourage you to read the blog post *[PowerShell and external commands done right](https://slai.github.io/posts/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/)* FYI.

However, there are a few ways to escape the quotes.  One way to include double quotes in a string is to use a single quote to encapsulate the whole string for example:

```
$String = 'video="Integrated Camera"'
```

Alternatively you can escape with a backtick:

```
$String = "video=`"Integrated Camera`""
```

Another way would be to escape using double `"`s:

```
$String = "video=""Integrated Camera"""
```

The method you chose will be down to personal preference and the readability of your code.
*It's worth noting that the -ArgumentsList expects an array of strings.*

Wrapping both of these up would give you something along the lines of:

```
$exe = "ffmpeg.exe"
$ffmpefArguments= "-f dshow i video=`"Integrated Camera`" c:\test.mp4"
&$exe $ffmpefArguments
```

Comment: Nice! You got a good answer up before I could finish typing it. I just wanted to add that you can double up your double quotes within other double quotes instead of using the backtick, such as `$ffshowargs = " -f dshow i video=""Integrated Camera"" c:\test.mp4"` .Also, `$args` is an automatic variable used by PowerShell and I would strongly advise against using that like the OP as done.