# Run an external program - differences between 'Start-Process' and '&'

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, video-processing

I would like to use `Start-process` to run ffmpeg. I can't get it to work properly as it doesn't do anything.

The `&$script:ffmpeg` does work with the same FFmpeg parameters, so they aren't the problem.

```
# vars
$Temp = 'C:\Temp';
$script:ffmpeg = "C:\encoder\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
$inputFile = 'C:\Temp\Sequence 07_1_08.mxf'
$outputFile = 'C:\Temp\testfile.mp4'

# Start-Process
$argument = "-i $inputFile -an -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -aspect 16:9 -flags +ildct+ilme -x264opts weightp=0:tff=1 $outputFile"
Start-Process $script:ffmpeg -ArgumentList $argument #-Wait -NoNewWindow

# &$script:ffmpeg
&$script:ffmpeg -i $($inputFile) -an -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -aspect 16:9 -flags +ildct+ilme -x264opts weightp=0:tff=1 $outputFile
```

Comment: just tested it with starting `cmd` and echoing arguments back, looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a space in your input filename "Sequence 07_1_08.mxf", so you'll need to use quotes around the file name *within* your arguments for the `ArgumentList` param. This starts to get complicated, so using the call operator (&) is often easier.

Using quotes within arguments is covered here so I'm not going to rewite an answer: [How to start a process in powershell with arguments in quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276486/how-to-start-a-process-in-powershell-with-arguments-in-quotes)

Comment: Damn, i didn't noticed the space. Thanks!